# How to import and render components dynamically in Svelte/Sapper?

Tags: svelte

I have a component (`IconInline.html`), within which I would like to import and render components dynamically based on a prop (`IconID`) passed to it.

Currently I do it manually like this:

```html
{{#if IconID === "A"}}
    <A />
{{elseif IconID === "B"}}
    <B />
{{elseif IconID === "C"}}
    <C />
{{elseif IconID === "D"}}
    <D />
{{/if}}

<script>
    import A from "./icons/A.html";
    import B from "./icons/B.html";
    import C from "./icons/C.html";
    import D from "./icons/D.html";

    export default {
        components: { A, B, C, D }
    };
</script>
```

Is there a way to

1. Import all components in a given directory dynamically?
2. Render a specific component that matches a given prop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to import all components in a given directory, but you can render components that match a specific prop using `<svelte:component>`:

```html
<svelte:component this={cmp} foo="bar" baz="bop">
  <!-- contents go here -->
</svelte:component>

<script>
  import A from "./icons/A.html";
  import B from "./icons/B.html";
  import C from "./icons/C.html";
  import D from "./icons/D.html";

  const components = { A, B, C, D };

  export default {
    computed: {
      cmp: ({ IconID }) => components[IconID]
    }
  };
</script>
```

If `IconID` was `"A"`, that would be equivalent to

```html
<A foo="bar" baz="bop">
  <!-- contents go here -->
</A>
```

[Docs here.](https://svelte.dev/examples#svelte-component)

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.

Comment: However, when replicating your example I get an error: `Module build failed: Error: ValidationError: Computed properties cannot use destructuring in function parameters`. Pointing to the curly brackets in the `cmp` function.

Comment: I now realize that I'm on version 1. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Changing it to `<:Component {cmp} />` syntax made it work. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah yep, it changed in v2. I definitely recommend upgrading as soon as you can :) You just need to do `npx svelte-upgrade v2 routes` — full migration guide [here](https://svelte.technology/blog/version-2), upgrade tool [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-upgrade)

Comment: @rich-harris - How do you do this with version 3?

Comment: `$: cmp = components[IconID];`